# Sending ether from one account to other account

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am using the below code in solidity to transfer ether from one account to another.

I am calling this from the owner's account.

But my ether gets deducted from owners and goes to contract address instead of the receiver/payee account.

```
 function PayCredit(address payable payee, uint money, uint invoiceNum) public payable{
        require(msg.sender==owner, "only owner can invoke it");
        payee.transfer(address(this).balance);
        claims[payee][invoiceNum].isPayed = true;
    }
```

Comment: Your code actually works as it should. Can you write a complete flow of what you trying to make?

Comment: Now you just sending the whole contract's balance to payee payee.transfer(address(this).balance);

Answer (score 3):

You are sending your ether's to contract address , change `address(this)` to `address` .

I would suggest you good practice of sending ether's to other account. Solidity transaction support value as argument and this is good place for sending ether(WEI) to other account . below code snippet will send 12 WEI to  other account.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract AB {
uint256 num1;
address owner;
constructor() public{
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function sendBal(address payable receiver) payable external onlyOwner {
    uint256 amount = msg.value;
    receiver.transfer(amount);  
}
```

[image: Illustrate how to call sendBal Function]